# The realms button is gone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

What do I do if the realms button is gone?
I tried getting an account on the mojang website get but it didn't show up. I've watched a bunch of tutorials too. However, they all do not work!

Comment: Is your account paid?

Comment: you are most likely using an outdated launcher or client.

Answer (score 2):

You are either:

- In a country that doesn't support realms, and you kind find what countries do and don't have realms from [this list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Realms#Availability) (Most countries should have it though)
- are not in online mode / connected to the internet, or
- are using an outdated client.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in offline mode or not connected to the internet the realms button will not display